# everytime showing same month while convert english date to arabic date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

in my app i am showing arabic date and toconvert that i am doing this code

```
func arabicdate()
{
    let inputDateAsString = dateToarabic

    print(inputDateAsString)
    // initialize formatter
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    // read input date as date
    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(inputDateAsString) {


        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_DZ")
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd,MMM,YYYY"

        dateToDisplay = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

        print(dateToDisplay) // الأربعاء, 9, مارس, 2016 10:33

    }


}
```

its give me a output but evrytime its showing this  جويلية

instead of يوليو

Comment: what is جويلية and يوليو meanings?

Comment: Why should it show `يوليو` instead of `جويلية`? This is not clear for me.

Comment: Can you give examples of values that `inputDateAsString` would have when you run this code?